# Authentication; accessing web service from .net core (5.0)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, authentication

I'm trying to access a jira server from .net (core 5.0 on Windows) desktop application.

If I use curl (WSL) like so:

```
curl -u userid:pwd -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.jira.com/rest/agile/1.0/board
```

JSON is returned.

I tried to something similar in .NET:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userid", "pwd");
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
var reply = wc.DownloadString("https://jira.jira.com/rest/agile/1.0/board");
```

and the download call throws a 401.

Interestingly, if I take the "Authorization" header generated by curl and add it to the headers (`wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx=");`).  The call works and returns JSON.

Two questions.

1. What does the 'Credentials' property do if it's not adding the header?
2. Is there a simply way to get the domain id info and pass on appropriate information so my application doesn't deal with user/pwd at all?

If you suggest MSAL for the second question please provide a simple example that doesn't require registering a client id (if possible).